# ¿Cómo puedo volver este código recursivo en Java?

Tags: java, recursión

Necesito volver este código recursivo (Es un algoritmo para calcular Pi con la serie de Basilea), la parte de la potencia ya se cómo volverla recursiva pero la función de Pi no.
(Soy estudiante de Ing. de sistemas, y apenas estoy empezando)

Este es el código:

```
public class Calcular_Pi {

        static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final double nt = 100;
        static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000000");

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            long start_nt = System.nanoTime();///Para calcular el tiempo que se demora
            int n = 100;///Hasta donde hace la sumatoria
            System.out.println("El numero π (Pi) con una precisión de 7 decimales es: " + df.format(pi(n)));///Llamo la función
            long end_nt = System.nanoTime() - start_nt;
            System.out.println("EL algoritmo gastó " + end_nt + " nanosegundos en su ejecución");///Para calcular el tiempo que se demora
        }


        public static double pi(int n) /*Necesito este recursivo*/{

            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                sum = sum + (1 / potencia(i, 2));///Hace la sumatoria, y llama la función para a potencia

                System.out.println(""+sum);
            }
            sum = sum * 6;///Multiplica entre 6 para eliminar el 6 de la serie de Basilea
            double sum1 = Math.sqrt(sum);///Hace la raíz cuadrada para eliminar el π^2 de la serie de Basilea
            return sum1;
        }   




        public static double potencia(int num, int num2)/*Este es de a potencia que ya se cómo colarlo recursivo*/ {
        double result = 1;
        if (num2 <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= num2; i++) {
            result = result * num;
        }
        return result;
    }
    }
```

Deseo volver la primera función recursiva.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto funcionaría.

```
public static double pi(int n) {
    return Math.sqrt(sumatoria(n)*6);
}

public static double sumatoria(int n) { //este sería el método recursivo

   if (n <= 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   return sumatoria(n-1) + (1.0 / (double)(n * n));
}
```

Comment: No funciona así

Comment: Ya lo modifiqué, ¿te funciona así?

Comment: Funciona mejor pero tiene un limite de n=13999, de 14000 en adelante muestra error "java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Comment: Un método recursivo puede agotar recursos, en este caso, la memoria. Un método recursivo debes implementarlo cuando sabes que no se va ciclar o no se va auto llamar demasiadas veces. Supongo que es a criterio del programador.

Comment: Yo en lo personal no calcularía pi en un método recursivo.

Comment: Excelente comentario amigo, gracias.